# Separate personal phone and company phone which were set up synchronized

Tags: ios, iphone

I bought a new iPhone 6 for personal use.  While at the store, we synced with my company phone to get all info.  Now I want my personal phone and company phone to be separate and to stop linking and synching. How?

Comment: could you provide more detail on what exactly is syncing? Is email, notes, apps, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new Apple ID and sign in (via iCloud, etc) to one for personal and one for business.

Comment: ...then re-purchase all your apps on the new ID.

Comment: use family sharing.

Comment: Not sure how you'd add a company to family sharing, hence I didn't mention it. [it had occurred to me, though]

Comment: You'd just be adding the Apple ID you are using for business purposes as a "family member" doesn't matter if it represents a company or a person, it's just an ID to Apple.